# "Connection closed before receiving a handshake response" with Sails.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, sails.js

I am getting `WebSocket connection to 'ws://<IP_ADDRESS>:1337/socket.io/?__sails_io_sdk_version=1.1.4&__sails_io_sdk_platform=browser&__sails_io_sdk_language=javascript&EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response` when going to a static html page.

The `module.exports.blueprints` in `config/blueprints.js` is empty. I've been looking around on the SailsJS documentation site, and I don't see any controller/action that needs to be explicitly defined.

I am using Sails `0.12.3`.

I've tried setting `'*': true` in `policies.js`.

I've tried making a new Sails project and setting up a static html page, and I can get the sockets to work for that app. I've gone through all the `config/*` files in the empty project, and the only differences I saw were the extra polices, `bootstrap.js` code, I added in my main project.

Both `config/sockets.js` objects are empty.

I'm confused on where Sails is supposed to be creating the handshake. I've searched in the Sails codebase for references to `Socket.io`, but I wasn't able to find much.

Any pointers to figure out where to start digging would be much appreciated.

EDIT: The static HTML page (in the original project) is in a Docker container, so I am trying to access my Sails app from a different IP. I originally had `useCORSRouteToGetCookie: false`, but when I change it to a route that returns `res.send('_sailsIoJSConnect();');` on the backend I get the handshake error.

Comment: Is this a fresh project or have you fiddled with the settings?

Comment: @Hiyper the project that I am having issues with is one I've fiddled with the settings over the course of a year or so.

Comment: I think is an issue with the sails.io.js library. I'm having the same problem but i can connect with socket.io-client library as well.